# Make FileInputStream fail on concurrent write

Tags: java, file, scala, file-io

I have an Java (must be Java 6 compatible) application running as a background service. The app reads file from the filesystem (read only). Since it is a service, I do not want to lock the files while reading. Nonetheless I want my application to fail if anyone else writes to the file while I am reading.

Here is a little test i set up (actually written in scala): First I create a 10 MB file with random content:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/random bs=1m count=10
```

Then here is my test:

```
package de.choffmeister.iotest

import org.specs2.mutable._
import java.io._
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

class IOSpec extends Specification {
  "Application" should {
    "run" in {
      using(new FileInputStream("/tmp/random")) { fs =>
        val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
        var done = false

        while (!done) {
          println("Reading 1 kB")
          val read = fs.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
          if (read > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(100)
          } else done = true
        }

        ok
      }
    }
  }

  def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](closable: A)(inner: A => B): B = {
    try {
      inner(closable)
    } finally {
      closable.close()
    }
  }
}
```

For those of you not familiar with Scala: It is just a simple loop that reads the file from start to end in 1 KB blocks. Between each read, there is a sleep so that the whole process takes some seconds.

Now when I override the while while reading (and hence while my FileInputStream is opened), then my application just thinks the file has been read in total and finishes without error.

How can I make my application throw an exception in case the file is manipulated while reading? And again: I want to allow changing the file while reading. I just want my application to notice so that it can for example retry.

Comment: I would start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: This is file notification for potentially a whole folder structure. I need way less: I only want to know if my file I currently reading from is changed... And the java.nio.FileWatcher is Java 7 and above only. I need a Java 6 solution (missed that, sry). In addition using a seperate observation approach introduces many race conditions. When I finished reading and get 1 ms later the notification, that the file was modificated: Have I finished reading before or after that change?

Comment: You could see if the last modified time has changed between opening and finishing reading, as long as you are sure nothing will reset it back to its original value after a modification.

Comment: I would suggest you .. Whatever the method who is going to write the file make that as `synchronized` and reading that file in background create as concurrent one... So I guess whenever writing the file starts reading will be halted as we are using `synchronized` for writing.. . I hope this would give you the Idea ..

Comment: The synchronization within my own application is no problem. I want to be sure that I recognize if the file has been modificated from outside of my application

Answer (score 0):

1) If file is only appended, track it's length in bytes -- if that is changed between reads, there must be somebody else

2) poll the [time of last modification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29), if there is change, there must be somebody else

Comment: Yeah I already thought about time of last modification... The files might be altered arbitrarily, hence solution 1) does not fit.